# Infinite House of Pancakes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In order to learn haskell, I wrote a solver for the [Infinite House of Pancakes](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p1) problem.

```
-- Solve the 'Infinite House of Pancakes' problem.
-- https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=p1

import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad

-- Generic solver code

readInt :: IO Int
readInt = readLn

readIntList :: IO [Int]
readIntList = getLine >>= return . map read . words

main :: IO [()]
main = do
  n <- readInt
  forM [1..n] (\i ->
    parse >>= putStr . printf "Case #%d: %d\n" i . solve)

-- Problem-specific code

parse :: IO [Int]
parse = getLine >> readIntList

cost :: Int -> Int -> Int
cost l n = if r == 0 then q - 1 else q where (q, r) = n `quotRem` l

test :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
test l = (+l) . sum . map (cost l)

solve :: [Int] -> Int
solve s = minimum . map (\l -> test l s) $ [1 .. maximum s]
```

I used [this python solution](https://github.com/vxgmichel/codejam-solver/blob/master/example/pancake.py) as a reference, which is based on the  [following problem analysis](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6224486/dashboard#s=a&a=1). I tested  my program using those [input](https://github.com/vxgmichel/codejam-solver/blob/master/example/B-large-practice.in) and [output](https://github.com/vxgmichel/codejam-solver/blob/master/example/B-large-practice.out.expected) files, and it seems to work fine:

```
$ stack ghc pancake.hs -- -O2
$ \time -f "%e s" ./pancake < B-large-practice.in | diff - B-large-practice.out
0.28 s
```

I'm looking for comments about the following points:

- coding style
- performance (currently runs in 0.28 seconds using `-O2`, against 5.5 seconds for python 3)
- bind operators vs do syntax (I used both  here, but it was mostly for educational purposes)
- tools and ecosystem (code analysis, better compilation flags, etc.)

---

**EDIT -** Thanks to @Gurkenglas answer, I've been able to improve this program quite a lot. Here's a [link to the corresponding gist](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/5f3cfc69e06dd149d6bc188a58f949cd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll refactor so every line tells the reader something about the program.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad
import Data.List.Split (splitPlaces)
import Safe (headNote)

main :: IO ()
main = interact                                                                -- no side effects
  $ (\f -> unlines . zipWith f [1..] . subList [2,4..] . lines)                -- embarassingly parallel
  $ (\solve (i :: Int) -> printf "Case #%d: %d" i . solve . map read . words)  -- mere math
  $ (\cost (s :: [Int]) -> minimum [cost l s | l <- [1 .. maximum s]])         -- brute optimization
  $ \l -> (+l) . sum . map ((`div` l) . subtract 1)

-- This gets a name because we ought to be importing it from a library.
subList :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
subList is = map (headNote "subList: index list not strictly ascending")
  . drop 1 . splitPlaces (zipWith (-) is $ 0:is)
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I tried to run it but there seems to be a few errors: `import Text.Printf` is missing, `ap` is not defined (I imagine you meant `map`) and the compiler complains about a few type issues.

Comment: I indeed didn't include that import you already had, I thought you would. `ap` is from `Control.Monad`, but here it's just `ap f g x = f x (g x)`. You're right on the errors, I tweaked it till it seems to compile.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. I've found the `interact` function,  the list comprehension, and the division trick to be very useful, it definitely improves the code. I have a few questions though: 1 - What do you mean by "embarrassingly parallel"? AFAIU, one needs to use [Control.Parallel)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parallelism) in order to achieve parallelism in Haskell. 2 - Does the application chain (one `$` per line) provide any advantage over the `where/let` statements or simply naming and adding the functions to the module?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel merely means that conceptually, the problem decomposes with no need for intercommunication. I preferred this form because it illustrates that after each line, there is only one value left to define, whereas a bunch of definitions might a priori recursively depend on each other.

Comment: `where` can encode this by repeatedly incrementing indentation. The right abstraction usually dissolves repeatedly incremented indentation. In fact, what we have here seems to be the `IxCont` pattern, but that particular wrapper does little and this usecase is simple.

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks for the explanation. With your advises, I've been able to [improve my code quite a bit](https://gist.github.com/vxgmichel/5f3cfc69e06dd149d6bc188a58f949cd). Note that I kept the problem logic separated from the solver logic in order to be able to re-use it for other problems (since GCJ problems usually share the same input and output formatting). Thanks again!